# If condition is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i have is a java script for light box for images and is working fine.

Problem arises when 'alt attribute is missing in image tag' script does not work properly.
But, if their is 'alt attribute in img tag or even blank' script work fine.
So, i want to add condition on it such that if 'alt attribute is missing or blank' then show text 'No Caption'.

Infected function:

```
    // CAPTION

captionOn = function() {
  var description = $('a[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"] img').attr('alt');
  if (description.length > 0)
    $('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>').appendTo('body');
},
captionOff = function() {
  $('#imagelightbox-caption').remove();
},
```

I have created a code snippet please check that out or https://jsfiddle.net/Bloggerz/a9yary1x/

For any other details pls comment.

```js
;
(function(e, t, n, r) {
  "use strict";
  var i = function() {
      var e = n.body || n.documentElement,
        e = e.style;
      if (e.WebkitTransition == "") return "-webkit-";
      if (e.MozTransition == "") return "-moz-";
      if (e.OTransition == "") return "-o-";
      if (e.transition == "") return "";
      return false
    },
    s = i() === false ? false : true,
    o = function(e, t, n) {
      var r = {},
        s = i();
      r[s + "transform"] = "translateX(" + t + ")";
      r[s + "transition"] = s + "transform " + n + "s linear";
      e.css(r)
    },
    u = "ontouchstart" in t,
    a = t.navigator.pointerEnabled || t.navigator.msPointerEnabled,
    f = function(e) {
      if (u) return true;
      if (!a || typeof e === "undefined" || typeof e.pointerType === "undefined") return false;
      if (typeof e.MSPOINTER_TYPE_MOUSE !== "undefined") {
        if (e.MSPOINTER_TYPE_MOUSE != e.pointerType) return true
      } else if (e.pointerType != "mouse") return true;
      return false
    };
  e.fn.imageLightbox = function(r) {
    var r = e.extend({
        selector: 'id="imagelightbox"',
        allowedTypes: "png|jpg|jpeg|gif",
        animationSpeed: 250,
        preloadNext: true,
        enableKeyboard: true,
        quitOnEnd: false,
        quitOnImgClick: false,
        quitOnDocClick: true,
        onStart: false,
        onEnd: false,
        onLoadStart: false,
        onLoadEnd: false
      }, r),
      i = e([]),
      l = e(),
      c = e(),
      h = 0,
      p = 0,
      d = 0,
      v = false,
      m = function(t) {
        return e(t).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() == "a" && (new RegExp(".(" + r.allowedTypes + ")$", "i")).test(e(t).attr("href"))
      },
      g = function() {
        if (!c.length) return true;
        var n = e(t).width() * .8,
          r = e(t).height() * .9,
          i = new Image;
        i.src = c.attr("src");
        i.onload = function() {
          h = i.width;
          p = i.height;
          if (h > n || p > r) {
            var s = h / p > n / r ? h / n : p / r;
            h /= s;
            p /= s
          }
          c.css({
            width: h + "px",
            height: p + "px",
            top: (e(t).height() - p) / 2 + "px",
            left: (e(t).width() - h) / 2 + "px"
          })
        }
      },
      y = function(t) {
        if (v) return false;
        t = typeof t === "undefined" ? false : t == "left" ? 1 : -1;
        if (c.length) {
          if (t !== false && (i.length < 2 || r.quitOnEnd === true && (t === -1 && i.index(l) == 0 || t === 1 && i.index(l) == i.length - 1))) {
            w();
            return false
          }
          var n = {
            opacity: 0
          };
          if (s) o(c, 100 * t - d + "px", r.animationSpeed / 1e3);
          else n.left = parseInt(c.css("left")) + 100 * t + "px";
          c.animate(n, r.animationSpeed, function() {
            b()
          });
          d = 0
        }
        v = true;
        if (r.onLoadStart !== false) r.onLoadStart();
        setTimeout(function() {
          c = e("<img " + r.selector + " />").attr("src", l.attr("href")).load(function() {
            c.appendTo("body");
            g();
            var n = {
              opacity: 1
            };
            c.css("opacity", 0);
            if (s) {
              o(c, -100 * t + "px", 0);
              setTimeout(function() {
                o(c, 0 + "px", r.animationSpeed / 1e3)
              }, 50)
            } else {
              var u = parseInt(c.css("left"));
              n.left = u + "px";
              c.css("left", u - 100 * t + "px")
            }
            c.animate(n, r.animationSpeed, function() {
              v = false;
              if (r.onLoadEnd !== false) r.onLoadEnd()
            });
            if (r.preloadNext) {
              var a = i.eq(i.index(l) + 1);
              if (!a.length) a = i.eq(0);
              e("<img />").attr("src", a.attr("href")).load()
            }
          }).error(function() {
            if (r.onLoadEnd !== false) r.onLoadEnd()
          });
          var n = 0,
            u = 0,
            p = 0;
          c.on(a ? "pointerup MSPointerUp" : "click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (r.quitOnImgClick) {
              w();
              return false
            }
            if (f(e.originalEvent)) return true;
            var t = (e.pageX || e.originalEvent.pageX) - e.target.offsetLeft;
            l = i.eq(i.index(l) - (h / 2 > t ? 1 : -1));
            if (!l.length) l = i.eq(h / 2 > t ? i.length : 0);
            y(h / 2 > t ? "left" : "right")
          }).on("touchstart pointerdown MSPointerDown", function(e) {
            if (!f(e.originalEvent) || r.quitOnImgClick) return true;
            if (s) p = parseInt(c.css("left"));
            n = e.originalEvent.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX
          }).on("touchmove pointermove MSPointerMove", function(e) {
            if (!f(e.originalEvent) || r.quitOnImgClick) return true;
            e.preventDefault();
            u = e.originalEvent.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
            d = n - u;
            if (s) o(c, -d + "px", 0);
            else c.css("left", p - d + "px")
          }).on("touchend touchcancel pointerup pointercancel MSPointerUp MSPointerCancel", function(e) {
            if (!f(e.originalEvent) || r.quitOnImgClick) return true;
            if (Math.abs(d) > 50) {
              l = i.eq(i.index(l) - (d < 0 ? 1 : -1));
              if (!l.length) l = i.eq(d < 0 ? i.length : 0);
              y(d > 0 ? "right" : "left")
            } else {
              if (s) o(c, 0 + "px", r.animationSpeed / 1e3);
              else c.animate({
                left: p + "px"
              }, r.animationSpeed / 2)
            }
          })
        }, r.animationSpeed + 100)
      },
      b = function() {
        if (!c.length) return false;
        c.remove();
        c = e()
      },
      w = function() {
        if (!c.length) return false;
        c.animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, r.animationSpeed, function() {
          b();
          v = false;
          if (r.onEnd !== false) r.onEnd()
        })
      };
    e(t).on("resize", g);
    if (r.quitOnDocClick) {
      e(n).on(u ? "touchend" : "click", function(t) {
        if (c.length && !e(t.target).is(c)) w()
      })
    }
    if (r.enableKeyboard) {
      e(n).on("keyup", function(e) {
        if (!c.length) return true;
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.keyCode == 27) w();
        if (e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39) {
          l = i.eq(i.index(l) - (e.keyCode == 37 ? 1 : -1));
          if (!l.length) l = i.eq(e.keyCode == 37 ? i.length : 0);
          y(e.keyCode == 37 ? "left" : "right")
        }
      })
    }
    e(n).on("click", this.selector, function(t) {
      if (!m(this)) return true;
      t.preventDefault();
      if (v) return false;
      v = false;
      if (r.onStart !== false) r.onStart();
      l = e(this);
      y()
    });
    this.each(function() {
      if (!m(this)) return true;
      i = i.add(e(this))
    });
    this.switchImageLightbox = function(e) {
      var t = i.eq(e);
      if (t.length) {
        var n = i.index(l);
        l = t;
        y(e < n ? "left" : "right")
      }
      return this
    };
    this.quitImageLightbox = function() {
      w();
      return this
    };
    return this
  }
})(jQuery, window, document);



$(function() {
  // ACTIVITY INDICATOR

  var activityIndicatorOn = function() {
      $('<div id="imagelightbox-loading"><div></div></div>').appendTo('body');
    },
    activityIndicatorOff = function() {
      $('#imagelightbox-loading').remove();
    },


    // OVERLAY

    overlayOn = function() {
      $('<div id="imagelightbox-overlay"></div>').appendTo('body');
    },
    overlayOff = function() {
      $('#imagelightbox-overlay').remove();
    },


    // CLOSE BUTTON

    closeButtonOn = function(instance) {
      $('<button type="button" id="imagelightbox-close" title="Close"></button>').appendTo('body').on('click touchend', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        instance.quitImageLightbox();
        return false;
      });
    },
    closeButtonOff = function() {
      $('#imagelightbox-close').remove();
    },


    // CAPTION

    captionOn = function() {
      var description = $('a[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"] img').attr('alt');
      if ( $.trim(description).length == 0)
      {
         description = "No caption";
      }
      $('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>').appendTo('body');
    },


    // NAVIGATION

    navigationOn = function(instance, selector) {
      var images = $(selector);
      if (images.length) {
        var nav = $('<div id="imagelightbox-nav"></div>');
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
          nav.append('<button type="button"></button>');

        nav.appendTo('body');
        nav.on('click touchend', function() {
          return false;
        });

        var navItems = nav.find('button');
        navItems.on('click touchend', function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (images.eq($this.index()).attr('href') != $('#imagelightbox').attr('src'))
              instance.switchImageLightbox($this.index());

            navItems.removeClass('active');
            navItems.eq($this.index()).addClass('active');

            return false;
          })
          .on('touchend', function() {
            return false;
          });
      }
    },
    navigationUpdate = function(selector) {
      var items = $('#imagelightbox-nav button');
      items.removeClass('active');
      items.eq($(selector).filter('[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"]').index(selector)).addClass('active');
    },
    navigationOff = function() {
      $('#imagelightbox-nav').remove();
    },


    // ARROWS

    arrowsOn = function(instance, selector) {
      var $arrows = $('<button type="button" class="imagelightbox-arrow imagelightbox-arrow-left"></button><button type="button" class="imagelightbox-arrow imagelightbox-arrow-right"></button>');

      $arrows.appendTo('body');

      $arrows.on('click touchend', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
          $target = $(selector + '[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"]'),
          index = $target.index(selector);

        if ($this.hasClass('imagelightbox-arrow-left')) {
          index = index - 1;
          if (!$(selector).eq(index).length)
            index = $(selector).length;
        } else {
          index = index + 1;
          if (!$(selector).eq(index).length)
            index = 0;
        }

        instance.switchImageLightbox(index);
        return false;
      });
    },
    arrowsOff = function() {
      $('.imagelightbox-arrow').remove();
    };



  var selectorF = 'a[data-imagelightbox="f"]';
  var instanceF = $(selectorF).imageLightbox({
    onStart: function() {
      overlayOn();
      closeButtonOn(instanceF);
      arrowsOn(instanceF, selectorF);
      navigationOn(instanceF, selectorF);
    },
    onEnd: function() {
      overlayOff();
      captionOff();
      closeButtonOff();
      arrowsOff();
      activityIndicatorOff();
      navigationOff();
    },
    onLoadStart: function() {
      captionOff();
      activityIndicatorOn();
    },
    onLoadEnd: function() {
      captionOn();
      activityIndicatorOff();
      $('.imagelightbox-arrow').css('display', 'block');
      navigationUpdate(selectorF);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
html {
  /* killing 300ms touch delay in IE */
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}
a img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* IMAGE LIGHTBOX SELECTOR */

#imagelightbox {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3.125em rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
/* ACTIVITY INDICATION */

#imagelightbox-loading,
#imagelightbox-loading div {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#imagelightbox-loading {
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10003;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
#imagelightbox-loading div {
  margin: 25%;
  width: 1.25em;
  height: 1.25em;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: imagelightbox-loading .5s ease infinite;
  animation: imagelightbox-loading .5s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imagelightbox-loading {
  from {
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.75);
  }
}
@keyframes imagelightbox-loading {
  from {
    opacity: .5;
    transform: scale(.75);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    opacity: .5;
    transform: scale(.75);
  }
}
/* OVERLAY */

#imagelightbox-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/* "CLOSE" BUTTON */

#imagelightbox-close {
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #666;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10002;
  top: 2.5em;
  right: 2.5em;
  -webkit-transition: color .3s ease;
  transition: color .3s ease;
}
#imagelightbox-close:hover,
#imagelightbox-close:focus {
  background-color: #111;
}
#imagelightbox-close:before,
#imagelightbox-close:after {
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
#imagelightbox-close:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#imagelightbox-close:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/* CAPTION */

#imagelightbox-caption {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0.625em;
}
/* NAVIGATION */

#imagelightbox-nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 3.75em;
  padding: 0.313em;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#imagelightbox-nav button {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.313em;
}
#imagelightbox-nav button.active {
  background-color: #fff;
}
/* ARROWS */

.imagelightbox-arrow {
  width: 3.75em;
  height: 7.5em;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10001;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -3.75em;
}
.imagelightbox-arrow:hover,
.imagelightbox-arrow:focus {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
.imagelightbox-arrow:active {
  background-color: #111;
}
.imagelightbox-arrow-left {
  left: 2.5em;
}
.imagelightbox-arrow-right {
  right: 2.5em;
}
.imagelightbox-arrow:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 1em solid transparent;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -0.125em;
}
.imagelightbox-arrow-left:before {
  border-left: none;
  border-right-color: #fff;
  margin-left: -0.313em;
}
.imagelightbox-arrow-right:before {
  border-right: none;
  border-left-color: #fff;
  margin-right: -0.313em;
}
#imagelightbox-loading,
#imagelightbox-overlay,
#imagelightbox-close,
#imagelightbox-caption,
#imagelightbox-nav,
.imagelightbox-arrow {
  -webkit-animation: fade-in .25s linear;
  animation: fade-in .25s linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 41.250em) {
  #imagelightbox-close {
    top: 1.25em;
    right: 1.25em;
  }
  .imagelightbox-arrow {
    width: 2.5em;
    height: 3.75em;
    margin-top: -2.75em;
  }
  .imagelightbox-arrow-left {
    left: 1.25em;
  }
  .imagelightbox-arrow-right {
    right: 1.25em;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 20em) {
  .imagelightbox-arrow-left {
    left: 0;
  }
  .imagelightbox-arrow-right {
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='images'>

  <a data-imagelightbox="f" href="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-w_GzlVRbQfY/VuKOdAE_emI/AAAAAAAAAVw/LRMazf4otRI4RY8Cmu1MjE7C0M9HII51g/s1600/demo1.jpg">
    <img alt='Sample caption' src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-w_GzlVRbQfY/VuKOdAE_emI/AAAAAAAAAVw/LRMazf4otRI4RY8Cmu1MjE7C0M9HII51g/s1600/demo1.jpg" />
  </a>

  <a data-imagelightbox="f" href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2s4gNMJNmvM/VuKO344_tgI/AAAAAAAAAWM/36_nKtGTZyQaFJ_EX2jzSm3wub7SA_jGg/s1600/demo2.jpg">
    <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2s4gNMJNmvM/VuKO344_tgI/AAAAAAAAAWM/36_nKtGTZyQaFJ_EX2jzSm3wub7SA_jGg/s1600/demo2.jpg" />
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: can you edit and post only the relevant part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the attribute `alt` exists, for that you can use the jQuery function [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) like this:

```
captionOn = function(){
    // Our image
    var img = $('a[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"] img');

    // Find if image has the alt attribute 
    if ($(img).is('[alt]'))
    {
        // If it does have. Get the value inside it and store it in the variable description
        var description = $(img).attr('alt');

        // Show the lightbox with value in description
        $('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>').appendTo('body');
    }
}
```

Or if you want a default value for `description` like for example 'No Caption'

```
captionOn = function(){
    // Our image
    var img = $('a[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"] img');

    // Declare a new variable with the default value.
    var description = 'No Caption';

    // Find if image has the alt attribute 
    if ($(img).is('[alt]'))
    {
            // If it does have. 
            // Get the value inside it and store it variable description
            description = $(img).attr('alt');
    }

    // Show the lightbox with the value stored in description
    $('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>').appendTo('body');
}
```

Comment: if alt does not exist then i want to show text 'No Caption' insted of description

Comment: I tried your changes but still error please check here https://jsfiddle.net/Bloggerz/a9yary1x/

Comment: Thanks 99999999999999999999999 times :-)

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your blog.

Answer (score 2):

> So, i want to add condition on it such that if 'alt attribute is
>   missing or blank' then show text 'No Caption'.

When the attribute is missing [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method returns undefined which is why `description.length` will fail.

You need to edit the captionOn method as

```
captionOn = function() {
      var description = $('a[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"] img').attr('alt');
      if ( $.trim(description).length == 0)
      {
         description = "No caption";
      }
      $('<div id="imagelightbox-caption">' + description + '</div>').appendTo('body');
}
```

Comment: are you able to find  $('#imagelightbox') from the the supplied snippet?

Comment: @user2181397 I think it is irrelevant. Since the problem is -  when the alt attribute is missing, then description will be undefined and description.length will give the error http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: yes its not working i have updated the snippet code with yours check that out.

Comment: @Bloggerz In that case  you need to share a fiddle

Comment: sorry but i don't know much about scripts. can you explain. :(

Comment: @Bloggerz where are you invoking your library?

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand

Comment: The library that you have written, you are not invoking it in your fiddle

Comment: Sorry brother but i said i don't know much about scripts. I applied this script from here http://osvaldas.info/image-lightbox-responsive-touch-friendly

Comment: @Bloggerz but you mentioned in your code that some part of it is working. If you have managed to get it working in your system, you can get it working on fiddle as well.

Comment: @Bloggerz In your fiddle, you have not even included jquery. You are not calling the library. No caption is shown for images. what is working?

Comment: Please check out the html part .

Comment: @Bloggerz checked it, where are you initializing the image container as per documentation from the website?

Comment: That was just to arrange images in html properly

Comment: @gurvinder372 are you able to understand me ?

Comment: @Bloggerz No, because I don't think library has been used in the fiddle the way it is documented in the website of osvaldas.

Comment: @gurvinder372 is lightbox shown when you click on image in provided fiddle or not ?

Comment: Finally i got it . i applied as @Fábio Antunes said and it works.

Comment: @Bloggerz finally got it, here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/a9yary1x/3/

Comment: yes, you got it thanks @gurvinder372 but i have other problem now. if two images have same link the value is recalled to first link: eg if i have 5 images and the link of img at 2nd and 4th position is same and i m navigation images with arrows of lightbox  after 3rd it again show 2nd and 3rd and again same i cannot navigate to 4th and 5th image with arrows but navigation dots are working here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Bloggerz/a9yary1x/4/